# Spring 4 Request driven Bean creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am implementing a Rest WS using Spring 4 (Spring Boot).

The basic idea is I want to consume a JSON payload specifying an identifier (e.g. social security number or something) and run multiple subServices on that identifier.
Here is a sample payload:

```
{
    "ssNumber" : "1111111111111111",
    "subServicesDetails" :
    [
        { "subServiceName" : "Foo" , "requestParameters" : {} }, 
        { "subServiceName" : "Dummy", "requestParameters" : {} }
    ]
}
```

In my code I have multiple "sub-services" (`FooService`, `DummyService`) implementing the `SubService` interface:

```
package com.johnarnold.myws.service;

import com.johnarnold.myws.model.SubServiceDetails;

public interface SubService {

    public boolean service(String ssNumber, SubServiceDetails ssd);
}
```

And below is the `FooService` code.
    package `com.johnarnold.myws.service`;

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.johnarnold.myws.dao.FooDao;
import com.johnarnold.myws.model.Foo;
import com.johnarnold.myws.model.SubServiceDetails;

@Component
public class FooService implements SubService{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(FooService.class);

    @Autowired
    private FooDao dao;


    public FooService()
    {
        log.debug("FooService ctor");
    }


    public boolean service(String ssNumber, SubServiceDetails ssd)
    {
        log.debug("FooService service");

        Map <String, String> responseParameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
        try
        {
            Foo foo = dao.getFoo(ssNumber);
            if(foo.isCompromised())
            {
                responseParameters.put("listed", "true");
            }
            else
            {
                responseParameters.put("listed", "false");              
            }
            ssd.setResponseParameters(responseParameters);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Throwable ex)
        {
            log.error("Exception in service ", ex);
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I wrote my own factory to create the subservices but when I did that of course because I am explictly creating my beans (e.g. FooService) below - my container is not auomatically injecting any of the @Autowired members - FooDao for example:
    package com.johnarnold.myws.service;

```
public class SubServiceFactory {

    /*
     * Instantiates a SubService for the supplied subServiceName or throws an exception if 
     * no valid SubService exists
     */
    public static SubService createSubService(String subServiceNameStr)
    {
        SubService subService = null;

        System.out.println("subServiceName [" + subServiceNameStr + "]");

        if(subServiceNameStr.equals("Foo"))
        {
            subService = new FooService();
        }
        if(subServiceNameStr.equals("Dummy"))
        {
            subService = new DummyService();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("subServiceName [" + subServiceNameStr + "] is not defined");    
        }
        return subService;
    }
}
```

For completeness here is the Controller:

```
package com.johnarnold.myws.controller;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.johnarnold.myws.model.RawsPayload;
import com.johnarnold.myws.model.SubServiceDetails;
import com.johnarnold.myws.service.SubService;
import com.johnarnold.myws.service.SubServiceFactory;
import com.johnarnold.myws.web.ValidMessage;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/raws/")
public class RawsController {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RawsController.class);    

    //@Autowired
    //SubService [] subSvcs;

    @RequestMapping(value="/{version}/status", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<ValidMessage> getServiceStatus()
    {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ValidMessage() , HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    /*
     * Main entry point - orchestrates all of the WS Sub Services
     */
    @RequestMapping(value="/{version}/raws", method=RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<String> raws(@Valid @RequestBody RawsPayload rawsPayload, 
            HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        logger.info("Request received");


        System.out.println("payl " + rawsPayload);

        System.out.println("ssNumber=" + rawsPayload.getSsNumber());
        System.out.println("sub svcs details=" + rawsPayload.getSubServicesDetails().length);

        SubServiceDetails[] subServiceDetails = rawsPayload.getSubServicesDetails();

        for(SubServiceDetails ssd : subServiceDetails)
        {

            String subServiceNameStr = ssd.getSubServiceName();

            System.out.println("svcname=" + subServiceNameStr);
            System.out.println("svc req params=" + ssd.getRequestParameters());
            System.out.println("svc resp params=" + ssd.getResponseParameters());

            SubService subService = SubServiceFactory.createSubService(subServiceNameStr);
            // Probably wrap the below with some timings
            subService.service(rawsPayload.getSsNumber(), ssd);
        }


        //System.out.println("svcs are " + subSvcs + "size=" + subSvcs.length);


        return new ResponseEntity<>("foo" , HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

And here is the main payload class:

```
package com.johnarnold.myws.model;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Length;

public class RawsPayload {
    static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(RawsPayload.class);

    @NotNull
    @Length(min=16, max=19)
    private String ssNumber;

    @Valid
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=3)
    private SubServiceDetails [] subServicesDetails;


    public String getSsNumber() {
        return ssNumber;
    }

    public void setSsNumber(String ssNumber) {
        log.info("setSsNumber()");
        this.ssNumber = ssNumber;
    }

    public SubServiceDetails[] getSubServicesDetails() {
        return subServicesDetails;
    }

    public void setSubServicesDetails(SubServiceDetails[] subServicesDetails) {
        this.subServicesDetails = subServicesDetails;
    }

}
```

I've read a number of answers on StackOverflow regarding Spring 4 Conditional Beans - but this functionality appears to be targeted at Context / Configuration type information rather than Request message content (as in this case).
Can anyone point me in the right direction. I can provide further context if necessary
KRgds
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need anything fancy here. Just implement all your services that implement your service interface, annotate them all with either `@Component` or `@Service` and scan them as usual.

Then, wherever you have to choose a concrete service implementation, autowire all implementations of your service like this:

```
@Autowired
Map<String, SubService> subServices;
```

The key of the map will be the name of the service as specified in the `@Component` annotation of every sub service implementation, and the value will be the instance.

So, when you receive you JSON, just get the name of the sub service (i.e. `Foo`), and get the specific service of the map:

```
SubService fooSubService = subServices.get(subServiceName + "Service");
```

where `subServiceName` is the uncapitalized name of the sub service you're receiving in your JSON (i.e. if you're receiving `Foo` this would be `foo`).

The convention is to use the uncapitalized name of the class that implements the interface as the bean name, i.e. for the `FooService` class the bean name will be `fooService`, and this is the key you have to look for in the map.

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ways of solving this problem:

- Add all your subService beans to the Spring context then select from them using a [ServiceLocatorFactoryBean](http://www.jcombat.com/spring/factory-implementation-using-servicelocatorfactorybean-in-spring). This is the nicer approach (from architectural point of view), but it might require a bit more time to implement if you have never used this concept before.

There is a simpler alternative below if you want to stick with basic Spring solutions:

- Have the subservice beans injected into your main service as a list, and then select from that. It would look something like this:

  `@Bean
  public List<SubService> subServices(){
      List<SubService> list = new SubService<>();
      list.add(new AService());
      list.add(new BService());
      return list;
  }`

THEN

```
public SubService selectServiceByName() {
    //iterate through the list, pick the service with the right name and return - this solution will require you to bind by beannames
}
```

Comment: Very educational answer

Answer (score 1):

@john-arnold First, crate all the services like this, or annotate them with @Service/@Component with explicit names like below: names are start with the values of `subServiceName` param and contains a common suffix, "Service" here, thats important.

```
@Bean("FooService")
public SubService fooService() {
    return new FooService();
}

@Bean("DummyService")
public SubService dummyService() {
    return new DummyService();
}
```

Then change your factory like this:

```
@Component
public class SubServiceFactory implements BeanFactoryAware{

private BeanFactory beanFactory;
private static final String MY_SERVICE_SUFFIX = "Service";

@Override
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}

public <T> T getServiceImplementation(String name, Class<T> requiredType) {
    return beanFactory.getBean(name + MY_SERVICE_SUFFIX, requiredType);
}
}
```

Now what we have here is a BeanFactoryAware class that you can inject to your Rest Endpoint and instead of if statement, try this:

```
subServiceFactory.getServiceImplementation(subServiceNameStr, SubService.class);
```

This will return your bean or an exception if it doesn't find one. If you don't want an exception, you can catch it and return null or you can create a Service imp. just for these and return that instance. Your choice.

Edit:

As a shortcut, you can define your imp. Beans and than add this to your rest endpoint

```
@Autowired
private Map<String, SubService> mySubServices;
```

Spring will automatically inject all your imp. ref.  so you can just use get() method of the map. But i prefer the first one..